# Convert CSS Declaration into a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I've written a script that extracts the `@font-face` declaration from CSS, and I'd now like to convert it into a javascript object. Here's an example of what the original string will look like:

```
{font-family:GT Alpina;font-weight:100;src:url(/next/contenthash/next/fonts/gt-alpina/thin/GT-Alpina-Standard-Thin.contenthash.3322f75174e682b58d25cca4c516f38b51edb6ef.woff2) format("woff2");font-display:swap}
```

Thats the string I'd like to convert into an object ^.

I tried using `JSON.parse()`, but it doesn't work since it's not a JSON encoded string. Is therea simple way that I'm missing to convert this string into a javascript object, or will I have to loop through it and manually convert it?

Any help is appreciated — thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The key point is using regex to convert CSS to JSON format and then using `JSON.parse`. A description of each `replace` part is included in the code.

```js
var css = '{font-family:GT Alpina;font-weight:100;src:url(/next/contenthash/next/fonts/gt-alpina/thin/GT-Alpina-Standard-Thin.contenthash.3322f75174e682b58d25cca4c516f38b51edb6ef.woff2) format("woff2");font-display:swap}';

cssObject = JSON.parse(css
  .replace(/"/g, '\\"')               // add \ before "
  .replace(/\s*\{\s*/, '{"')          // add start "
  .replace(/\s*;?\s*\}\s*/, '"}')     // add end "
  .replace(/\s*:\s*/g, '":"')         // replace : with ":"
  .replace(/\s*;\s*/g, '","')         // replace ; with ","
);

console.log("CSS Object: ", cssObject);
```

To convert keys to camel format another `replace` is required as the following code:

```js
var css = '{font-family:GT Alpina;font-weight:100;src:url(/next/contenthash/next/fonts/gt-alpina/thin/GT-Alpina-Standard-Thin.contenthash.3322f75174e682b58d25cca4c516f38b51edb6ef.woff2) format("woff2");font-display:swap}';

cssObject = JSON.parse(css
.replace(/"/g, '\\"')               // add \ before "
  .replace(/\s*\{\s*/, '{"')          // add start "
  .replace(/\s*;?\s*\}\s*/, '"}')     // add end "
  .replace(/\s*:\s*/g, '":"')         // replace : with ":"
  .replace(/\s*;\s*/g, '","')         // replace ; with ","
  .replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, (full, property) => '"' + property.toLowerCase().replace(/-(\w)/, (a, b) => b.toUpperCase()) + '":')
);

console.log("CSS Object with Camel Format: ", cssObject);
```